# Can we access the list of invalid controls the UA is supposed to maintain for HTML5 forms api?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

From how I'm interpreting the [constraint validation spec](http://goo.gl/fllOIZ), (in particular, part 3.1-3), UA's maintain a list of invalid controls which, I assume, comes before any reporting of problems to the user (i.e. the list is fully populated before an error is shown to user).

Is there a way to get at those invalid controls? I'm envisioning putting something in a submit handler that uses the invalid controls, if any, to populate a DOM element and display to user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. The list you are refering to is private. But you can get thos fields using a simple pseudo class selector ':invalid'.

In case you want to get those invalid elements you can simply write:

```
//This of course only works in HTML5 API supporting browsers:
//pure JS:
var invalidList = documet.querySelectorAll('form.my-class :invalid:not(fieldset)');

//or jQuery (in case you use webshims this will also work in IE7+)
var invalidList = $('form.my-class :invalid:not(fieldset)');
```